# How to join two publishers based on a common attribute and construct a single publisher out of it, in Spring reactor/ web flux?

Tags: java-8, project-reactor

Suppose I have two fluxes `Flux<Class1>` and `Flux<Class2>` and both Class1 and Class2 have a common attribute, say "id".

The use case is to join the two fluxes based on the common attribute "id" and construct a single `Flux<Tuple<Class1, Class2>>`, similar to joining two sql tables.

-There will always be a 1 to 1 match, for the attribute id, between the two fluxes.

-The fluxes won't contain more than 100 objects.

-The fluxes are not ordered by id.

How do I achieve this in Project Reactor/Spring web flux?

Comment: A `Flux` is a **potentially infinite** stream of data - your requirement means that you may have to buffer all the elements of both streams until you find matching ids. How do you want to apply backpressure in this situation?

Comment: does each id exist in both Fluxes exactly once?

Comment: Given what [you've said in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3811763/uneq95) (which you should add to this question), I would suggest taking one `Flux` and then querying the other table for each id in that `Flux`. That way you avoid the nasty `O(n^2)` type degeneracy and take advantage of Cassandra's strenghts - indexing. You should be able to add the query to your repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- both collections aren't very big (you can hold them in memory without risking OOM issues)
- they're not sorted by id
- each element in a collection has its counterpart in the other

First, you should make those `Class1`, `Class2` implement `Comparable` or at least prepare a comparator implementation that you can use to sort them by their id.

Then you can use the `zip` operator for that:

```
Flux<Class1> flux1 = ...
Flux<Class2> flux2 = ...
Flux<Tuple2<Class1,Class2>> zipped = Flux.zip(flux1.sort(comparator1), flux2.sort(comparator2));
```

`Tuple2` is a Reactor core class that lets you access each element of the Tuple like this

```
Tuple2<Class1,Class2> tuple = ...
Class1 klass1 = tuple.getT1();
Class2 klass2 = tuple.getT2();
```

In this case, `sort` will buffer all elements and this might cause memory/latency issues if the collections are large. Depending on how the ordering is done in those collections (let's say the ordering is not guaranteed, but those were batch inserted), you could also buffer some of them (using `window`) and do the sorting on each window (with `sort`).

Of course, ideally, being able to fetch both already sorted would avoid buffering data and would improve backpressure support in your application.

Comment: I want to join the two objects only if they both have the same value for the attribute id. I don't think zip does that here.

Comment: That's not what i want. I want to club the objects from tbe two fluxes only when the objects have got the same attribute. But, what you have answered has clubbed the elements without any condition and then filters by checking the condition, which might not be what i want.

Comment: then the last part of my answer is right - if you want to join elements just like you'd do with sql tables, you first need to buffer/collect and then do the pairing thing.

Comment: I'd like to help here, but you need to refine your question - is there a guarantee to have a 1 to 1 match between the two fluxes (are you sure you'll find the same id in each?). How big are those collections? Can you get them ordered by id in the first place?

Comment: Yes, there will always be a 1 to 1 match, for the attribute id, between the two fluxes. The size of the collections would be no more than 100. I am not getting the fluxes ordered by id, but it can be sorted by id using the sort() operator, right?

Comment: edited - please amend your question to reflect our discussion here.

Comment: @uneq95 "_The size of the collections would be no more than 100_" - then why use `Flux` at all? If you have collections, then just pair them together and build a new collection.

Comment: @BoristheSpider because I have to implement this logic in a reactive way, as I am using spring web flux for this.

Comment: If you have collections @uneq95, then it's by definition not reactive. Adding some fluxes and monos does not make things magically "reactive" - it's a way of dealing with data that is _already_ reactive. Stop making your life needlessly complicated.

Comment: They are not collections, per se. I am getting a fluxes from two different repositories and I have to join them if they both have the same value of the common attribute "id"

Comment: if they're spring data repositories, you can certainly get them sorted in the first place.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am using Cassandra, so I can't join at the database level

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work with the following constraints:

- the 2nd `Flux` needs to emit the same elements to all subscribers since it gets subscribed to over and over again.
- this is basically the equivalent of a nested loop join so highly inefficient for large fluxes.
- every element of the first `Flux` has a matching element in the second one.

  ```
  flux1.flatMap(
      f1 -> flux2.filter(f2 -> f2.id.equals(f1.id)).take(1)) // take the first with matching id
            .map(f2 -> Tuple.of(f1,f2))) // convert to tuple.
  ```

*writen without IDE. Consider pseudo code.*

Comment: _OUCH_. This is nasty. It would require a query for `f2` for every element of `f1` - unless you buffer `f2`. Either way OUCH.

Comment: if the fluxes aren't ordered, to begin with, I don't think there is an alternative to buffering them.

Comment: It would make more sense, given the OP has [described the problem more fully](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3811763/uneq95), to take one `Flux` and then zip it with a query for each id. At least that way you take advantage of what Cassandra is good at, indexing.

Comment: Oh, great a mutating question. :-( BTW your link goes to the user profile.

Comment: Yeah, one of those.. (oops - too late to fix it now, apologies)